# При сборке проекта libgdx через gdx-setup, он мне пишет что не смог выделить 1,5гб места из озу

Tags: libgdx

При сборке проекта libgdx через gdx-setup, он мне пишет что не смог выделить 1,5гб места из озу, хотя у меня на компе 4гб озу. Из-за чего это?

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю почему, но после того как я поменял 1,5гб требуемого озу на 1гб, все заработало